# Dynamic Template Builder ASP.NET CMS - Rolling My Own

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, content-management-system

I am currently building my own CMS for various reasons that could take a long to explain...

However I am looking for a dynamic solution to create templates for pages within the CMS and all areas must be editable via the administration area, maybe large text areas broken into multiple areas, text and image area on a page etc.

----- edit -----

Following on from the above I would like to create the following:

Create a new page (selecting a pre-defined template like below)

[image: example]
http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/9872/nestedpages.png

and then upon editing the page it would have created as many text editors required for each editable region or a file upload control for an image area.

I am thinking of using nested masterpages for the design elements, just unsure the best-practice way to achieve the above (db structure etc)

I some how hope this provides a little more information.

Comment: You are very far from providing enough information. What is an area in your context? A placeholder? Do you want to provide a way to edit templates (put ASP.NET controls and HTML in them) through the user interface? Why not use masterpages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to get anywhere with this?

I am planning on creating a custom templating system which will contain my own custom defined controls alongside, text areas, images, headers etc... I was thinking these could be inside an editable div container.

A master page could be used to create the menu, i.e. the place where the configuration off the template could be done e.g. landscape or vertical view, set size of page, how many columns?